# Which is the best practice to follow client side or server side validation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Which is the best practice to follow either client side validation or server side validation using php and what to follow and why to follow?

Comment: Very unclear, please elaborate

Comment: Read online tutorials, read books - code snippets - articles etc about this. Why ask a question thats been answered so many times before?

Comment: i've seen a lot of question like this, don't link it here because you only need to search the title of your question...

Comment: Im working on form and i did my form validation using ajax and not submitting my form.This can be done with php server side validation. so which is the best to follow for secure data transfer?

Comment: secure data transfer has nothing to do with validation.  For validation issues see my answer.  For secure transfer of data you need to do some research on technologies such as https, encryption etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would say both.

Client side validation is important for confirmation to the user of what exactly it is they are doing wrong and why.  This can be a real time update and does not require any server side interaction (although it can).

Server side validation is for your confirmation rather than the users to check that the information provided is indeed correct and what you would expect.

Both have their place and are equally as useful as one another.

Answer (score 0):

The server side validations must include the use of strip_slashes to prevent the SQL injection attacks...

On the client side, do the necessary validations and checks using Jquery or JavaScript so as to reduce the load of the server...

You can altogether ignore them but if your app has a lot of traffic then you should consider this but the server side validations are a must...

Comment: >>must include the use of strip_slashes to prevent the SQL injection attacks<< thats not true. it depends on server configuration, but you should use mysqli::real_escape_string

Comment: Not correct in either case, you should be using mysqli or PDO prepared statements which negate the need for real_escape_string.  Secondly I don't think they were talking about databases, they were talking about form validation (I think)

Comment: Also **never** rely on client side validation, just to reduce load on the server, this is very bad as I can easily bypass client side validation and submit malicious content which you should **always** be checking server side.